# Armature duplication causing problems

Tags: armature

I'm currently learning about rigging, skinning and animating, but I've run into a problem with a part of my armature. The scale, rotation and position of my mesh and armature on right side has been applied, I've duplicated the armature for the arm, hand and fingers, mirrored it to the left side on the X axis, but for some reason a part of the arm is twisted. I tried resetting the rotation, scale and position using Alt + G, R, and S, which has helped, but it's still not right. To begin with, the arm was twisted round like a sausage. This is what it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: If you've given your forearm an IK constraint, you might need to play with its Pole Angle value to correct this kind of twist

Comment: I don't believe it has. I'm following a book on character creation. There is an arm pole, but the book never said about parenting it to anything, though the right arm is perfectly fine. It only mentions adding an IK target at the wrist to control the arm.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, if there's an arm pole, it means that you must have given your arm an IK constraint, please check and try to play with its Pole Angle value. If it's not that, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I'll upload my save as I can't see where I've gone wrong or what to try.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5522/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct the *IK Pole Angle* value of your forearm:

- First, select your armature and in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Colors* go back to *Default Colors* so that you can see where are the constraints. You can see that your forearms have an *IK* constraints (green bones).
- In *Pose* mode, select its right forearm (the one on our left) and go in the *Properties* panel > *Bone Constraints*. Now play with the *Pole Angle* value to correct the rotation. You often needs to do this after giving an *IK* constraint so that Blender knows how the bone is supposed to be oriented.

[image]